# I cannot send an email on failure using Apache airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to send an email on failure to my own GMAIL account.

I followed up some other recommendations for configuring SMTP server

```
[smtp]
smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = something@gmail
smtp_port = 587
smtp_password = 16_chars_long_app_password
smtp_mail_from = something@gmail
```

I changed my logs to DEBUG but I am not able to find where the problem is.

I have my dag args with

```
'email': ['something@gmail.com'],
'email_on_failure': True,
```

I force the tasks to be failed or the DAG to have status failed, so I don't know if it might be because I am forcing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add subject and content template files to airflow.cfg (https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#email-configuration):

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp

subject_template = /path/to/my_subject_template_file      
html_content_template = /path/to/my_html_content_template_file
```